# I need to go few websites and grab specific data set

Tags: selenium, katalon-studio

Looking for a way to go to a few websites (10 sites) and grab a set of data, need a proper way to do since I am new to coding.

code:

```
WebUI.openBrowser('');
WebUI.navigateToUrl("www.site1.com");
WebUI.maximizeWindow();
String text1 = WebUI.getText(findTestObject("xpath"));
```

Do I need to do this for all the 10 websites?

Comment: why don't you loop it ?

Comment: How would you do it manually?

Comment: I have a set of values and need to compare those with 10 sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have the 10 URLs in an array. Create another empty array that will hold the text values:

```
WebUI.openBrowser('');
def mySites = ["www.site1.com", "www.site2.com", "www.site3.com", "www.site4.com", "www.site5.com", "www.site6.com", "www.site7.com", "www.site8.com", "www.site9.com", "www.site10.com"];
def myTexts = [];
```

Then loop your above code in a for loop, and add the text values to the array (note: xpath element name is the same for all the sites in this example, you should edit that according to your needs):

```
for(i=0; i<mySites.size; i++){

    WebUI.navigateToUrl("www.site1.com");
    WebUI.maximizeWindow();
    myTexts << WebUI.getText(findTestObject("xpath"));
}
```